# How to check if user pressed Enter key ?

Tags: c, string, user-input

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "formatCheck.h"
int main()
    {
    char input[32];
    char format[32]
    printf("enter your format : ");
    fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);
    sscanf(input,"%s",format);
        //my problem
        //if user don't enter format it will exit.
         if()
            {
            return 0;
            }
    }
```

How can I check if user doesn't input anything (just Enter key).
Sorry about English.
Thanks.

Comment: `if (input[0] == '\n') return 0;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When user hits only enter, `input[0] contains \n`

```
fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);
  if(input[0]=='\n') printf("empty string");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read about the [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) family of functions you will see that they returns the number of successfully scanned "items". So if your `sscanf` call doesn't return `1` then there was something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the length of input text is 0 or `NULL`.

Comment: The length of a string after a `fgets` call will only be zero one condition: That there was an EOF directly. Otherwise it will either be undefined (if the `fgets` call failed) or *at least* one as the newline will be there.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* fgets example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   FILE * pFile;
   char mystring [100];

   pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt" , "r");
   if (pFile == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
   else {
     if ( fgets (mystring , 100 , pFile) != NULL ) //Use this
       puts (mystring);
     fclose (pFile);
   }
   return 0;
}


/* fgets example 2 */
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   FILE * pFile;
   char mystring [100];

   pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt" , "r");
   if (pFile == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
   else {
     if ( fgets (mystring , 100 , pFile) && input[0]!='\n' ) //Use this
       puts (mystring);
     fclose (pFile);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Reference : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/